# Generate single global infowindow for all Google markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have this code that I get from another post. I am new to JavaScript and tried to modify it so that when I click a marker, I want the previous infowindow to close before the new infowindow opens to keep the map clean. I know this question have been answered so many times.

I have done my research trying to fix this code but my lack of java has limited me.

This is my source:

```js
function cCustomMapping(options) {
    var self = this;
    var pOptions = options,
        pData, pMap;
    var currentInfoWindow = null;
    var activeWindow
    self.getOptions = function() {
        return pOptions;
    };

    self.setData = function(data) {
        pData = data;
        return pData;
    };

    self.getData = function() {
        return pData;
    };

    self.afterResetBoundingBox = function(bounds) {
        // called when map size is adjusted to bounds
        return bounds;
    };

    self.beforeMapRendering = function(myOptions) {
        // make any map rendering adjustments here
        return myOptions;
    };

    self.afterMapRendering = function(theMap) {
        // store map opject
        pMap = theMap;
        return pMap;
    };

    self.afterMarkerCreate = function(cj) {
        // play around with marker info window etc.
        return cj;
    };

    self.setParams = function(qParams) {
        // play around with parameters
        pParams = qParams;

        return pParams;
    };

    self.getParams = function() {
        return pParams;
    };

    self.markerOnClick = function(cj) {
        // when a marker is clicked
        return cj
            //setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
    };

    self.markerAfterClick = function(cj) {
        // affter a marker click is processed
        return cj;
    };

}

function mcpherDataPopulate() {
    var mcpherData = {
        'framework': {
            'control': {
                'browser': 'default',
                'zoomlevelonselect': 18,
                'resizeboundingbox': 1,
                'shape': 'circle'
            }
        },
        'cJobject': [

            {
                'title': '007',
                'content': '\<b\>7 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>6480 ANDERSON ST\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.059088',
                'lng': '-75.172762',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '010',
                'content': '\<b\>10 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>6463 ARDLEIGH ST\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.057609',
                'lng': '-75.172873',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '011',
                'content': '\<b\>11 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>6475 ARDLEIGH ST\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.0579279',
                'lng': '-75.173392',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '012',
                'content': '\<b\>12 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>6610 ARDLEIGH ST\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.058337',
                'lng': '-75.175411',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '017',
                'content': '\<b\>17 - (19150)\</b\>\<br\>1501 Barringer St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.062211',
                'lng': '-75.166986',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19150'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '018',
                'content': '\<b\>18 - (19150)\</b\>\<br\>1534 Barringer St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.062918',
                'lng': '-75.165485',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19150'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '019',
                'content': '\<b\>19 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>1215 E Cardeza St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.059621',
                'lng': '-75.171835',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '020',
                'content': '\<b\>20 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>1231 E Cardeza St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.060054',
                'lng': '-75.171412',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '021',
                'content': '\<b\>21 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>1235 E Cardeza St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.060166',
                'lng': '-75.171306',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '022',
                'content': '\<b\>22 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>1236 E Cardeza St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.059989',
                'lng': '-75.170865',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '023',
                'content': '\<b\>23 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>1313 E Cardeza St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.061115',
                'lng': '-75.170365',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '024',
                'content': '\<b\>24 - (19119)\</b\>\<br\>1335 E Cardeza St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.061804',
                'lng': '-75.169701',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19119'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '025',
                'content': '\<b\>25 - (19150)\</b\>\<br\>1607 E Cardeza St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.064291',
                'lng': '-75.167243',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19150'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '026',
                'content': '\<b\>26 - (19150)\</b\>\<br\>1332 E Cliveden St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.061041',
                'lng': '-75.168595',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19150'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '027',
                'content': '\<b\>27 - (19150)\</b\>\<br\>1407 E Cliveden St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.061981',
                'lng': '-75.16842',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19150'
                }],
            },

            {
                'title': '028',
                'content': '\<b\>28 - (19150)\</b\>\<br\>1607 E Cliveden St\<br\>',
                'lat': '40.064017',
                'lng': '-75.166444',
                'color': '#0000FF',
                'size': '0',
                'category': [{
                    'ZipCode': '19150'
                }],
            }

        ]
    };

    return mcpherData;
};

// -- this section is main
function initialize() {

        mcpherData = mcpherDataPopulate();
        customMapping.setData(mcpherData);

        if (mcpherData.cJobject.length > 0) {
            mcpherData.cJobject.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.title.toLowerCase() < b.title.toLowerCase() ? -1 : (a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0);
            });

            var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(mcpherData.cJobject[0].lat, mcpherData.cJobject[0].lng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            // get parameters if any
            var qparams = mcpherGetqparams();
            qparams = customMapping.setParams(qparams);

            var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
                cj[i].childIndex = i;
                bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(cj[i].lat, cj[i].lng));
            }

            if (!qparams['zoom']) qparams['zoom'] = 2;
            myOptions['zoom'] = parseInt(qparams['zoom']);
            // create the map

            // opportunity to change options
            myOptions = customMapping.beforeMapRendering(myOptions);

            gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            gMap.fitBounds(bounds);

            customMapping.afterMapRendering(gMap);

            // add the excel data
            for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
                mcpherAddMarker(cj[i]);
            }

            // Set up combox

            category();
            quickLink(-1);
            makeFlightGroups();
            initialCategory();
        }
    }
    //----


//---- this section is catfacunctions
// flightpath stuff
function createSquareCoords(p, size) {
    // size will be in meters convert to km
    return [
        destinationLatLng(p, size / 1000, 45),
        destinationLatLng(p, size / 1000, 135),
        destinationLatLng(p, size / 1000, 225),
        destinationLatLng(p, size / 1000, 315),
        destinationLatLng(p, size / 1000, 45)
    ];
}

function destinationLatLng(p, size, heading) {
    var d = size / earthRadius();
    var lat1 = toRadians(p.lat());
    var lon1 = toRadians(p.lng());
    var brng = toRadians(heading);
    var lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(d) +
        Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(brng));
    var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(lat1),
        Math.cos(d) - Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2));
    lon2 = (lon2 + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;
    return new google.maps.LatLng(fromRadians(lat2), fromRadians(lon2));

}

function earthRadius() {
    return 6371.0;
}

function toType(obj) {
    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
}

function isArray(arg) {
    return toType(arg) == 'array';
}

function toRadians(deg) {
    return Math.PI / 180 * deg;
}

function fromRadians(rad) {
    return 180 / Math.PI * rad;
}

function createFlightGroups() {
    var flightGroups = [];
    var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;
    var fg;
    for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
        if (fg = cj[i].flightGroup) {
            if (flightGroups.indexOf(fg) == -1) {
                flightGroups.push(fg);
            }
            cj[i].flightGroupIndex = flightGroups.indexOf(fg);
        } else cj[i].flightGroupIndex = -1;
    }
    return flightGroups;
}

function initialCategory() {
    // sets initial category using the first select element
    var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;
    var c, p;
    var combos = getAllCombos();
    if (combos.length > 0) {
        var cats = createCategories(combos[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
            if (c = cj[i].startCategory) {
                if ((p = cats.indexOf(c)) != -1) {
                    var elem = document.getElementById('selectcategory0');
                    elem.value = p;
                    dealWithCategories(elem);
                    return p;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

// this is because IE doesnt have indexOf...
if (!Array.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
        for (var i = (start || 0); i < this.length; i++) {
            if (this[i] == obj) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

function resetBoundingBox(force) {
    var z = mcpherData.framework && mcpherData.framework.control && mcpherData.framework.control.resizeboundingbox ?
        mcpherData.framework.control.resizeboundingbox : false;
    if ((z || force) && !vMap) {
        // dont do for vizmap apps - reset bounding box to visible items
        var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
            if (cj[i].marker.visible) bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(cj[i].lat, cj[i].lng));
        }
        gMap.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    customMapping.afterResetBoundingBox(bounds);
}

function makeFlightGroups() {

    var flightGroups = createFlightGroups();
    var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;

    for (var j = 0; j < flightGroups.length; j++) {
        var flightCoords = [];
        var color = "#FF0000";
        for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
            if (j == cj[i].flightGroupIndex) {
                flightCoords.push(cj[i].marker.position);
                if (cj[i].flightColor) color = cj[i].flightColor;
            }
        }
        if (flightCoords.length) {
            flightGroups[j].flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightCoords,
                strokeColor: color,
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                map: gMap
            });
        }
    }
    return flightGroups;
}

function createPoly(cj, p) {
    if (cj.size) {
        if (mcpherData.framework.control.shape == "square") {
            return new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: createSquareCoords(p, cj.size),
                strokeColor: cj.color,
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                map: gMap,
                fillColor: cj.color,
                fillOpacity: 0.20
            });
        } else { // assume circle for backward comp.
            var circle = {
                strokeColor: cj.color,
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: cj.color,
                fillOpacity: 0.20,
                map: gMap,
                center: p,
                radius: parseFloat(cj.size),
            };
            return new google.maps.Circle(circle);
        }
    }
}
infoWindowClosed = true;

function mcpherAddMarker(cj) {
    var p = new google.maps.LatLng(cj.lat, cj.lng);
    cj.circle = createPoly(cj, p);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: p,
        map: gMap,
        title: cj.title
            //icon: 'https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_black.png'
    });
    cj.marker = marker;
    //cj.infowindow = null;

    if (cj.image) marker.setIcon(cj.image);
    if (cj.content) {
        var c = document.createElement("div");
        c.innerHTML = cj.content;


        cj.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: c
        });
        //google.maps.event.addListener(cj.marker, 'click', function() {
        //cj.infowindow = null;//cj.infowindow.open( null, null ); 

        //markerClick(gMap, cj);

        //});
        //}
        //cj = customMapping.afterMarkerCreate(cj);

        //return cj.marker;
        //}  /
        google.maps.event.addListener(cj.marker, "click", function() {
            markerClick(gMap, cj);
            //cj = customMapping.markerOnClick(cj);
            //if (cj.infowindow) cj.infowindow.close();
            //cj.infowindow.open(omap, cj.marker);
            //cj.infowindow.open (omap,cj.marker);
            //adjustZoom(cj);
            //cj = customMapping.markerAfterClick(cj);
            //cj.marker.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
        });
    }
    cj = customMapping.afterMarkerCreate(cj);
    return cj.marker;
}

function markerClick(omap, cj) {
    cj = customMapping.markerOnClick(cj);
    cj.infowindow.open(omap, cj.marker);
    adjustZoom(cj);
    cj = customMapping.markerAfterClick(cj);
    cj.marker.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
    //currentInfoWindow = cj.infowindow;
}

function adjustZoom(cj) {
    var z = mcpherData.framework && mcpherData.framework.control && mcpherData.framework.control.zoomlevelonselect ?
        parseInt(mcpherData.framework.control.zoomlevelonselect) : null;
    if (z) {
        if (gMap.getZoom() == z) {
            resetBoundingBox(true);
        } else {
            gMap.setZoom(z);
            gMap.setCenter(cj.marker.getPosition());
        }
    }

}

function mcpherGetqparams() {
    // get parameters
    var ps = {};
    location.search.substr(1).split("&")
        .forEach(function(p) {
            ps[p.split("=")[0]] = p.split("=")[1]
        });
    return ps;
}


function dealWithQuickLink(selValue) {
    if (vMap) {
        var nextSpot = vMap.spots[selValue];
        vMap.gotoAnotherSpot(vMap.currentSpot, nextSpot);
        if (vMap.provider == 'maps') nextSpot.createInfoWindow(0);
    } else {
        var cj = mcpherData.cJobject[selValue];
        if (cj.infowindow) {
            cj.infowindow.open(gMap, cj.marker);
        }
        adjustZoom(cj);
        return cj.infowindow;
    }
}

function findMySpot(cj) {
    // return the spot to which this cj belongs
    if (vMap) {
        for (var i = 0; i < vMap.spots.length; i++) {
            if (cj.SpotID === vMap.spots[i].spotId) return (vMap.spots[i]);
        }
        return null;
    } else
        return cj;

}

function dealWithCategories() {
    var combos = getAllCombos();
    // start by not showing anything, except where theres no categories
    var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;
    for (var j = 0; j < cj.length; j++) {
        var mySpot = findMySpot(cj[j]);
        mySpot.marker.setVisible(combos.length == 0);
        if (mySpot.circle) {
            mySpot.circle.setVisible(combos.length == 0);
        }
    }
    // need appear in each category

    for (var j = 0; j < cj.length && combos.length > 0; j++) {
        var show = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < combos.length; i++) {
            var selElem = document.getElementById('selectcategory' + i);
            if (selElem.value != 0) {
                // we have a filter operating
                var cats = createCategories(combos[i]);
                var target = cats[selElem.value];
                if (vMap) {
                    var c = cj[j];
                    if (c.hasOwnProperty(combos[i])) {
                        if (c[combos[i]] == target) show[i] = true;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var k = 0; k < cj[j].category.length; k++) {
                        for (m in cj[j].category[k]) {
                            if (m == combos[i]) {
                                if (cj[j].category[k][m] == target) show[i] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                show[i] = true;
            }
        }
        // show it?
        var x = 0;
        for (var k = 0; k < combos.length; k++) {
            if (show[k] === true) x++;
        }
        if (x == combos.length) {
            var mySpot = findMySpot(cj[j]);
            mySpot.marker.setVisible(true);

            if (mySpot.circle) {
                mySpot.circle.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }
    // reset to show only filtered spots
    quickLink();

}

function quickLink(selCategory) {
    var comboElem = document.getElementById('comboquicklink');

    if (comboElem) {
        if (selCategory == -1) { //first time in
            var selElem = document.createElement('select');
            selElem.id = "quickLinks";
        } else {
            var selElem = document.getElementById('quickLinks');
            selElem.options.length = 0;
        }
        // depends on type of app
        var cj = vMap ? vMap.spots : mcpherData.cJobject;

        mcpherAddEvent(selElem, "change", function() {
            dealWithQuickLink(selElem.value);
        }, false, true);

        for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
            // only show visible spots
            var workit = true;
            if (cj[i].marker) workit = cj[i].marker.visible;
            if (workit) {
                var o = document.createElement('option');
                o.text = cj[i].title;
                o.value = i;
                selElem.value = o.value;
                try {
                    selElem.add(o, null);
                } catch (error) {
                    selElem.add(o);
                }
            }
        }

        comboElem.appendChild(selElem);
    }
    resetBoundingBox();
}

function createCategories(categoryName) {
    var cats = [];
    var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;
    for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
        // find the matching object
        if (vMap) {
            if (cj[i].hasOwnProperty(categoryName)) {
                if (cats.indexOf(cj[i][categoryName]) == -1) cats.push(cj[i][categoryName]);
            }
        } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < cj[i].category.length; j++) {
                if (cj[i].category[j].hasOwnProperty(categoryName)) {
                    if (cats.indexOf(cj[i].category[j][categoryName]) == -1) cats.push(cj[i].category[j][categoryName]);
                }
            }

        }

    }
    cats.sort().splice(0, 0, 'all categories');
    return cats;
}

function category() {

    var comboElem = document.getElementById('combocategory');
    if (comboElem) {
        var combos = getAllCombos();
        for (var j = 0; j < combos.length; j++) {
            var selElem = document.createElement('select');
            selElem.id = "selectcategory" + j;
            var cats = createCategories(combos[j]);
            mcpherAddEvent(selElem, "change", function() {
                dealWithCategories(selElem);
            }, false, true);

            for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
                var o = document.createElement('option');
                o.text = cats[i];
                o.value = i;
                try {
                    selElem.add(o, null);
                } catch (error) {
                    selElem.add(o);
                }
            }
            var d = document.createElement('span');
            var t = document.createTextNode(combos[j]);
            d.appendChild(t);
            d.appendChild(selElem);
            comboElem.appendChild(d);

        }
    }
}

function getAllCombos() {
    var combos = [];
    if (vMap) {
        for (var i = 0; vMap.framework.spots.categories && i < vMap.framework.spots.categories.length; i++)
            combos.push(vMap.framework.spots.categories[i]);
    } else {
        var cj = mcpherData.cJobject;
        for (var i = 0; i < cj.length; i++) {
            if (isArray(cj[i].category)) {
                for (var j = 0; j < cj[i].category.length; j++) {
                    for (k in cj[i].category[j])
                        if (combos.indexOf(k) == -1) {
                            combos.push(k);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return combos;
}

// this section is functions as far as after /head

function mcpherAddEvent(o, e, f, b, complain) {
    // because IE is different
    if (o.addEventListener) return (o.addEventListener(e, f, b));

    else if (o.attachEvent) return (o.attachEvent('on' + e, f));
    else if (complain) alert('browser doesnt support events');

    return (null);

}

var mcpherData;
var gMap;
var vMap;
var customMapping = new cCustomMapping({
    type: 'default'
});
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: Gray;
    background-color: WhiteSmoke;
}
#map_canvas {
    height: 100%
}
.mcquicklink {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    float: right;
}
.mccategory {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: inline;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    float: right;
}
.mcheading {
    display: inline;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
    <style type='text/css'>
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://apis.google.com/js/client.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://xliberation.com/t/gas/js/scriptdbapi.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://xliberation.com/t/gas/js/firsttime.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://xliberation.com/cdn/js/ccookie.js'></script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="comboquicklink" class="mcquicklink">Quick Links</div>
    <div id="combocategory" class="mccategory"></div>
    <div id="heading" class="mcheading">Tax Sale Map by Chrisol Real-estate
        <a href="http://phillyanyhouse.com">phillyanyhouse.com</a>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 90%"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please paste your relevant code directly to the question instead of linking it. (Myself and possibly others may not be able to view it, and it's much easier to answer if it's easy to access.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to modify `markerOnClick` function, in that case once the next info window will be initialized the current (`currentInfoWindow`) will be closed:

```
self.markerOnClick = function (cj) {
        // when a marker is clicked
        if (currentInfoWindow) currentInfoWindow.close();  //close current info window  
        currentInfoWindow = cj.infowindow; //save current info window
        return cj;
};
```

Comment: You Nailed it! Thank you very much. Three days of digging. It is working like  a charm now.